# How do I insert XML into another XML file with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, insert

I looked at this thread to find out how to insert XML into XML with XSLT [Insert XML node at a specific position of an existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862954/insert-xml-node-at-a-specific-position-of-an-existing-document)

But I have a problem since I need to insert XML between two grand child nodes.
For example I want to insert `<s>...</s>` between `<r>...</r>` and `<t>...</t>` in this file

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <a>...</a>
    <r>...</r>
    <t>...</t>
    <z>...</z>
  </child1>
</root>
```

to create this file

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <a>...</a>
    <r>...</r>
    <s>...</s>
    <t>...</t>
    <z>...</z>
  </child1>
</root>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you only looking for XSLT based solution? How about just xpath and some java coding?

Answer (score 2):

A standard "identity transform" plus one template to match element `<r>` and insert `<s>...</s>` afterwards:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="r">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <s>...</s>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If the answwer solved your problem, it's customary to mark it "accepted" by clicking on the checkbox at the top left of the answer.